# selecting CRAN mirror from remote device

Tags: r, remote-access, cran

I am running jobs remotely, and the cluster I am running it on does not have the R package I require. I have tried to install it using:

```
if(!require(hglm)){install.packages("hglm");require(hglm)}
```

and realise that I am required to select a CRAN mirror. I tried adding:

```
selectCRANmirror()
```

to the script, but received the error message, cannot select CRAN mirror non-interactively.

I then tried adding:

```
selectCRANmirror(ind=72)
```

as this is what I would use on my local computer to set the CRAN mirror to UK(St. Andrews), but this generates the error message:

```
Error in chooseCRANmirror(ind = 72) : unused argument(s) (ind = 72)
```

I was wondering if anyone could explain how to select the CRAN mirror on a remote device?

I amended my script to include the line suggested:

```
if(!require(hglm)){install.packages("hglm",repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

replacing with "http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran" (St. Andrews mirror)
and received the following message (I have included preceding scripts to help illuminate where the problem lies):

```
setwd("~/lustre2/s0784669")
load("df1QCMAF.RData")
.libPaths('~/RLibrary')
if(!require(GenABEL)){install.packages("GenABEL");require(GenABEL)}
#Loading required package: GenABEL
#Loading required package: MASS
#GenABEL v. 1.7-6 (May 16, 2013) loaded
if(!require(hglm)){install.packages("hglm",repos="http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran");require(hglm)}
#Loading required package: hglm
#Installing package(s) into '/export/users/s0784669/RLibrary'
#(as 'lib' is unspecified)
#Warning: unable to access index for repository http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/src/contrib
```

I have tried:

```
library(RCurl)
url.exists("http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran")
```

to ascertain internet access on the cluster and received the following message:

```
library(RCurl);
#Loading required package: bitops
url.exists("star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran")
#[1] FALSE
```

Suggesting no internet access. So would I have to access source code? And is this accessible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a CRAN mirror in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488174/how-to-select-a-cran-mirror-in-r)

Comment: I've checked this out, and my problem is slightly different, because it is being run on a sun grid cluster, so I upload the whole script to one of the nodes and it goes through it start to finish, so I cannot interact with the computer once I have set the script running.

Comment: I tried the accepted answer, but it still would not run, see amended question.

Comment: Does the cluster have internet access? Try `library(RCurl); url.exists("http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran")`.

Comment: Error message:
> library(RCurl);
Loading required package: bitops
> url.exists("http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran")
[1] FALSE
Does this mean no internet access?

Comment: That's the error you get when R can't access the web, so probably. If you can retrieve the source from CRAN and send it to the cluster, [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source) will be helpful for installing from local source.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34379/discussion-between-lynsey-hall-and-thomas)

Answer (score 1):

Per `?install.packages`:

> `repos`
>   character vector, the base URL(s) of the repositories to use, e.g., the URL of a CRAN mirror such as "http://cran.us.r-project.org".

So do something like `install.packages("hglm", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")`. Insert the url to St Andrews instead.

Comment: I tried this, but received the error message which I have added to my question above. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, then I tried this and it worked:

```
chooseCRANmirror(ind = 77)
```

With this code being put in front of any `install.packages()` statements, you can run the whole R script and successfully install packages non-interactively. Although it's been 7 years I hope this works for you and it could work for others!