# Installing mhurdle on OS X 10.9.1

Tags: r, cran

I am trying to install a package

```
install.packages("mhurdle")
```

But I get a warning:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0

Warning message:
package ‘mhurdle’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

I get the same message for different packages..Not sure how to proceed from here! I am using a OS X 10.9.1.

Comment: Try setting a different CRAN mirror: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488174/how-to-select-a-cran-mirror-in-r

Comment: There's always the fallback: manually D/L packages from CRAN and install from local.