# R 3.4.1 is timing out on the installation of new packages

Tags: r

I have just updated my R 3.4.0 to R 3.4.1 and my package installation has started timing out.

It looks like R is having trouble with accessing URLs:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
```

I tried different CRAN mirrors, but still getting the same issue.
Any thoughts around this are much appreciated.

Comment: Since you added the `RStudio` tag, please determine if the problem has anything to do with RStudio: Try installing packages using RGui or the terminal. If it works, then your problem is RStudio. If it doesn't, then your problem isn't RStudio and you should remove the tag.

Comment: Maybe try another mirror? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488174/how-to-select-a-cran-mirror-in-r

Comment: I have tried few mirrors as I mentioned in my question too, but no success.