# Impossible to install packages in RStudio depending on the version of R

Tags: r, package, rstudio, version

I have installed R (version 4.3.1) and RStudio (version 2023.06.2). When I try to install any package I get the following message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

Nevertheless, when I change the R version into (R 4.1.3) I can install any package, I do not get any issue.

I searched similar questions but I did not find a solution. Most of them suggest to disable "Use secure download method for HTTP", which was de way I had since the begining.
Moreover I entered into R program and I wrote `install.packages("ggplot2") getting the same result as above (which seems to be not a RStudio issue).

Any idea of what is going on?

---

Doing several test, I realized that it was a connection problem, because when I used a different network I was able to download packages. Nevertheless, I am still working on the arrangement of the problem.

Comment: Try using a different CRAN mirror.

Comment: https://github.com/EBI-predocs/research-software/issues/75

Comment: When you say "different CRAN mirror" do you mean when I select the country from which download the libraries? I changed it and I got the same message.

Comment: If you get an identical message, you failed to change the mirror to a valid one.

Comment: It is  weird that any of the mirros tried worked (UK, Spain, the globla, . . .)

Comment: You can see the list of CRAN mirrors here - https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html and how to select a CRAN mirror here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488174/how-to-select-a-cran-mirror-in-r